# A tuple parser in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, tuples

I've been trying to learn functional parsing in Haskell, and as an exercise I want to write a simple tuple parser, using the functions `between` and `sepBy1` in `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`.  Essentially I want `tupleAsIntPair :: ReadP (Int, Int)`, which when parsed using `ReadP_to_S` takes a string such as `"(3,4)"` and returns the pair of integers `(3,4)` boxed in a `ReadS`.  Currently I have:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

isNumericOrSep :: Char -> Bool
isNumericOrSep = flip elem $ "0123456789-, "

tuplify2 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
tuplify2 [x,y] = (x,y)

tupleAsIntPair :: ReadP (Int, Int)
tupleAsIntPair = fmap tuplify2 parsedList 
    where   parsedList = fmap (map read) $ sepBy1 noparens sep
            noparens = between open close $ many1 (satisfy isNumericOrSep)
            open = char '('
            close = char ')'
            sep = char ','
```

However, when I try to run `(readP_to_S tupleAsIntPair) "(3,4)"`, I get a no parse error.  On the other hand, if I define `noparens` globally and run `(readP_to_S noparens) "(3,4)"`, I get `[("3,4","")]` and if I run `(readP_to_S $ sepBy1 (many1 $ satisfy isNumericOrSep) sep) "3,4"`, I get a list `[(["3"],",4"),(["3,"],"4"),(["3","4"],""),(["3,4"],"")]`, so at least the parser `sepBy1` is doing something, even though I only want the third parsing.

I think I'm composing the two parsers `between` and `sepBy1` incorrectly, or maybe `sepBy1` is not doing what I think it should.  How do I actually implement this tuple parser?  I would also appreciate any stylistic advice (e.g., `tuplify2` bugs me a little).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is your definition of `isNumericOrSep`. The list you are defining contains `,` as an element. This means that `isNumericOrSep` will parse the `,` that you're using as separator, therefor `parsedList` will fail, due to the missing `sep`.

```
isNumericOrSep :: Char -> Bool
isNumericOrSep = flip elem $ "0123456789- "
```

So, wouldn't you want to define `isNumeric`? Why do you need the separator in this definition?

The second problem is the order of your combinators. Your description parses `sep` between two `noparens`, where `noparens` is defined as the combination of an opening parenthesis, many (but at least one) numeric values and a closing parenthesis. So, I guess what you really want is to parse a tuple between the opening and closing parenthesis.

```
tupleAsIntPair :: ReadP (Int,Int)
tupleAsIntPair = fmap tuplify2 parsedList
 where
  parsedList = fmap (map read) $ between open close $ sepBy1 noparens sep
  noparens = many1 (satisfy isNumericOrSep)
  open = char '('
  close = char ')'
  sep = char ','
```

This yields the following result:

```
 *Main> (readP_to_S tupleAsIntPair) "(3,4)"
 [((3,4),"")]
```

It's possible, that I misinterpret what you're aiming for. But in your introduction, I read that you want to parse one tuple - but maybe you want to parse many tuples?

EDIT:

The parentheses aren't parsed first. Take a look at the definition of [`between`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#between):

```
between :: ReadP open -> ReadP close -> ReadP a -> ReadP a
-- ^ @between open close p@ parses @open@, followed by @p@ and finally
--   @close@. Only the value of @p@ is returned.
between open close p = do _ <- open
                          x <- p
                          _ <- close
                         return x
```

The order is left to right, again. First `open`, then the parser `p` and at the end `close` is parsed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help; this was exactly what I wanted.  Just to check, the code first removes the parentheses and then parses the comma list, right?  So should I think of parsers composing from left to right?

Comment: Yes to the second question, when you compose parsers, it's more natural to do that from left to right. For the second answer, I'm going to edit my answer.